# In Xamarin BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization doesn't Work

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding, xamarin.uwp

i get always on Xamarin with UWP the following Error:

The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

I want to use:

Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization(MyList, null, ObservableCollectionCallback);

I won't use:

Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => MyList.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));

I have my reasons.

Here is the very simple c# ViewModel Code. You have to bind MyList in a Xamarin Project with UWP in MainPage to a ListView:

```
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization(MyList, null, ObservableCollectionCallback);
        Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(Addtext));
        timer.Change(3000, 1000);
    }
    void ObservableCollectionCallback(IEnumerable collection, object context, Action accessMethod, bool writeAccess)
    {
        lock (collection)
        {
            accessMethod?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public void Addtext(object state)
    {
        MyList.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> MyListValue;

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
    {
        get { return MyListValue; }
        set
        {
            MyListValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

is anybody here who know, what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

> In Xamarin BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization doesn't Work

The problem is that you invoke `Addtext` in the `Timer`. And the timer triggered in the un-uithread. If you don't want to use `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, you could use [`Device.StartTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device#devicestarttimer)  to replace `Timer`.

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),()=> {
    Addtext(this);
    return true;
} );
```

And please check [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=netcore-3.1#moniker-applies-to) list, EnableCollectionSynchronization could not support UWP plafrom.

Comment: The Timer is an easy example for a non UI-Thread. The realy Code is to complex. I need a Solution why "Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization" doesn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid it could not [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=netcore-3.1#moniker-applies-to) uwp platform.